# Statistics and Probability: What is the probability that a student did not play the piano?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I've been having some difficulty with the problem below:

[image]

For part a I said that the probability is $\frac{(n-1)^k}{n^k}$ since the bottom represents the total number of ways of choosing a student and the top whenever a student is not chosen. However, I'm not sure if it's right. For part b, am I supposed to plug in $2n\log(n)$ for $k$ for the answer that I got from part A?

Comment: Find another piano teacher.

Comment: haha...........

Comment: Try inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: For part b? Because I know for sure part a is right. I just don't know what I'm supposed to part b. Like do I have to plug for k?

Comment: P(nobody played) = P({Alice never played} U {Bob never played} U ...)

Comment: ah i see now. Thanks for the hint

Comment: I got a summation 1-((n-1)^k)/n^k, and then substituting for k and taking log I got: log(n-1)/log(n)

Comment: Please write your own thoughts on the question in the question body, so that it's easy to follow.

Comment: never mind i got the answer